# Accepting answer for question posted through unregistered account from other account

Tags: support

I created a Mathematics StackExchange account today. Unfortunately, before this, I posted  [a question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1779540/is-complex-conjugate-distributive-over-exponentiation)  as a guest (unregistered user). As my browser blocks cookies, I have lost access to this account. I have followed the instructions given on the relevant help center page, and hopefully, I will soon receive a response. In the meantime, however, the question has been answered. Is it somehow possible for me to accept an answer?

Comment: Nope, not possible. If/when the account merge is done, you can accept. Let's hope it gets done quickly.

Comment: Hmm, maybe what you did wasn't the best thing, [merging accounts](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) would be the thing to do.

Comment: I followed the instructions given on that page.

Comment: Let's hope for the best.

Comment: This stuff wouldn't happen if we [required registration to ask a question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/17244)...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's commendable that you want to accept an answer, but there is no rush. Even under normal circumstances, it is perfectly normal to wait a few days before accepting an answer. (There **is** such a thing as accepting too quickly.) And many answered questions remain without an accepted answer forever, which isn't ideal but is not a big deal, either.

If a Stack Exchange employee merges your accounts, great; otherwise, just move on.